# How to access methods in android?

Tags: android, class, methods, android-activity

I have two classes as follows,

Settings.java

```
public class Settings extends Activity{
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.general_settings);

              // some code here

   }

public String getDateFormat() {

    //Some code here

   }
}
```

The second class,

DateFormat.java

```
public class DateFormat {

private DateDisplayFormat(){}

public static final String DEFAULT = "dd-MM-yyyy";
public static final String MON_DEFAULT = "MM-dd-yyyy";

    // I want to access the method here
public static String getFormattedDate(Calendar calendar){
    return getFormattedDate(DEFAULT, calendar.getTime());
}

public static String getFormattedDate(Date date){
    return getFormattedDate(DEFAULT, date);
}

public static String getFormattedDate(String format, Calendar calendar){
    return getFormattedDate(format, calendar.getTime());
}

public static String getFormattedDate(String format, Date d){
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    return formatter.format(d);
}

}
```

And my doubt is that I want to access the getDateFormat() method from the second class to get the resulting string. I tried accessing by Settings.getDateFormat(), but it didn't work. Please help me with this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: make `DateFormat` class an inner class of your activity class

Comment: I want to access the DateFormat class from various parts of the app, hence I created it separately.

Comment: What code do u have in `getDateFormat()` ?

Comment: So can I have an alternate solution Mocialov Boris?

Comment: @PrakashJackson Do `getDateFormat()` need to be in the activity or could it be moved in another class?

Comment: Yes getDateFormat() can be anywhere, I just want to access my database to retrieve the string from it @Roberto Lombardini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple,

Declare getDateFormat() in Settings.java as static:

i.e.

```
public static getDateFormat()
{
   ...
   ...
}
```

Now in your DateFormat.java call the functions using its class name.

i.e. use:

```
Settings.getDateFormat()
```

in your DateFormat class.

This is the concept of "static" keyword.

Comment: I tried the way that you suggested, but still I can't access the getDateFormat() from the second class

Comment: Syntax error on token "getDateFormat", Identifier expected after this token -- This is the error message I'm getting

Comment: I think then you need to do it using the old way: Setting s=new Setting(); and once this object is created you can call its member functions, that is s.getDateFormat() i'm sure this will work. May be you need to remove the static keyword in this case.

Comment: Can you please try this: Settings.class.getDateFormat() ?

Comment: thanks for your answer but the above answer just doesn't work. I just need to retrieve the string from the DB either from Settings.java class or DateFormat.java class.

Comment: @PrakashJackson please answer my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

These classes can be initialise in your main activity and through there you can assess it.

```
public class Settings extends Activity{
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.general_settings);

              // some code here
            DateFormat dateformate_class=new  DateFormat();

 }
```

And through its object you can access its functions and methods.

Comment: can you please tell how to access the method using this object from DateFormat class? @Curtis Nehls

Answer (score 0):

You can also use composition. Add DateFormat class as a variable in your activity.

Comment: It will be a -has a- relationship. Setting(activity) has a DataFormat.                                              'private DataFormat dataFormat;'

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that i didn't fully understand what you are tring to achieve. I have two possible solution and depends on the implementation of `getDateFormat()`.
The first one is the case in which you have a different `getDateFormat()` methods in every single class in which u use `getFormattedDate()`. Then your class

```
public class GenericActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.generic_activity);

       // some code here

       DateFormat.getFormattedDate(this.getDateFormat(), genericCalendar);

    }

    public String getDateFormat() {

        //Code customized for this GenericActivity

    }
}
```

Otherwise if you need only one implementation of `getDateFormat()`, then you should put it the DateFormat class like this:

```
public class DateFormat {

    private DateFormat() {
    }

    public final String DEFAULT = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    public final String MON_DEFAULT = "MM-dd-yyyy";

    // I want to access the method here
    public String getFormattedDate(Calendar calendar) {
        return getFormattedDate(DEFAULT, calendar.getTime());
    }

    public String getFormattedDate(Date date) {
        return getFormattedDate(DEFAULT, date);
    }

    public String getCustomFormattedDate(Calendar calendar) {
        return getFormattedDate(this.getDateFormatFromDB(), calendar.getTime());
    }

    private String getFormattedDate(String format, Date d) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        return formatter.format(d);
    }

    private String getDateFormatFromDB() {
        //DB access code here
    }
```

}